# How to choose one image out of three? The rest has to be invisible

Tags: javascript, html

I'am making a game. You can choose one bokser out of three as your own bokser. Than you can choose the enemy, also one image out of three. After you choose your own bokser and the enemy. Both images has to be visible the rest invisible.

This is my HTML

```
<div id="jouwbokser">
<h1>Kies Jouw Bokser!</h1>
<img id="bokser1" src="img/bokser1.png" alt="bokser" /><!--Bron:proksa.pl-->
<img id="boker2" src="img/bokser2.png" alt="bokser2" /><!--Bron:www.weekendowo.pl-->
<img id="bokser3" src="img/bokser3.png" alt="bokser3" /><!--Bron:www.ufc.com-->

</div>


<div id="computer">
<h1>Kies je Tegenstander</h1>
<img id="bokser4" src="img/bokser1.png" alt="bokser" /><!--Bron:proksa.pl-->
<img id="bokser5" src="img/bokser2.png" alt="bokser2" /><!--Bron:www.weekendowo.pl-->
<img id="bokser6" src="img/bokser3.png" alt="bokser3" /><!--Bron:www.ufc.com-->

</div>
```

Has anyone an idea how?

https://jsfiddle.net/o7m1w2qk/

Comment: i mean boxer, as a fight game

Comment: What have your tried? Your fiddle has no javascript code.

Comment: because I have no idea how te start.....

Comment: Will the game be all in Javascript, or is there server-side code involved?

Comment: To be honest the code has to be in javascript

Answer (score 0):

There is a huge amount of how to do this. It's all depend on your requirements, environment, browsers support, whatever.

For example using jQuery:

```
$("img").on("click", function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var $div = $this.parent();
    $div.addClass("has-selected");
    $("img", $div).removeClass("selected");
    $this.addClass("selected");
});
```

CSS:

```
#jouwbokser.has-selected > img:not(.selected),
#computer.has-selected > img:not(.selected) {
    display: none;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/o7m1w2qk/1/

UPDATE

Non jQuery solution:

```
var onclickImg = function(event) {
    var img = event.target;
    var div = img.parentElement;
    for (var i = 0; i < div.children.length; i++) {
        var child = div.children[i];
        if (child.nodeName != "IMG") {
            continue;
        }
        child.className = "";        
    }
    div.className = "has-selected";
    img.className = "selected";
}

imgs = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
for (var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
    imgs[i].addEventListener('click', onclickImg);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/o7m1w2qk/3/

Comment: Can you write it in javascript? It has to be with an if/else statement.........Thank you very much